# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at .../Signature.asmx/SendIdDocuments

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I have created a webservice using vb.net. It as an asmx class that contain:

```
'To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following 
line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")>
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class Signature
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
 Public Function SendIdDocuments(ByVal idPaziente As Object)
 MsgBox("sucessssssss")
 MsgBox(idPaziente)
 Return "test"
 End Function
 End Class
```

I invoke this ws from ajax:

```
  function callService() {    
  $("[id*=documentiGrid] input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
  selected.push(row.cells[6].innerHTML);
  });

  selectedJson = JSON.stringify(selected);
     $.ajax({
                url: '.../Signature.asmx/SendIdDocuments',
                data: selectedJson,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",      
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("succes");
                },              
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log("error");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log("failure");
                }
            });
    }
```

I call callService() function in a button click. When I try this from postman it works perfectly but when I try this from my project it throws this error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://.../Signature.asmx/SendIdDocuments. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://.../Signature.asmx/SendIdDocuments. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

I saw some choices for cross origin blocked which says that changing data-type from json to jsonp solves the issue, but jsonp is used just for GET method and in my case doesnt work because I need to use POST.
Any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a website, it is hosted somewhere like http://localhost:9000, or if it's a real live site, somewhere like http://www.somesite.com

The pages of that site may contain javascript. That javascript may make GET and POST requests, and it could reasonably be anywhere on the web that it sends those requests

The browser knows the javascript was served from http://localhost:9000 (or the real site.. wherever.. it has a single origin that it was served from), so if it catches the javascript attempting to access http://awesomeapi.com/some/senddocuments url it goes "hey.. http://awesomeapi.com didn't serve this javascript up, so this javascript is clearly trying to hit third party web services.. Before I do as it asks, I'll just check with the third party service that it's OK"

So, before the browser acts on your code's request to GET http://awesomeapi.com ..., it sends its own request: `OPTIONS http://awesomeapi.com/some/senddocuments` and takes a look at the response. That is awesomapi.com opportunity to either grant the action, or tell you to get stuffed. To grant, it must respond with a header saying "yeah, http://localhost:9000 is permitted to access me for GET", at which point the browser will know its approved and it goes and does the `GET http://awesomeapi.com/some/senddocuments` your code is requesting

Or awesomeapi's server can tell your code to get stuffed; it does this by not sending the expected response back. Either it sends an error response, or it sends a response that doesn't mention localhost:9000, or one of the allowed methods.. or whatever

The cards are stacked against you at this point; if the OPTIONS request fails for any reason or doesnt have the right info in it, your code request fails with an error like you see there

To get this to work out your web server *must* respond with a valid CORS response.. I'm not even sure what that looks like, since your question contains 3 dots - either you really have coded `...` and the ajax really has done an options on it, or you've subbed the real host for ... in your question.

Either way, the webserver at `...` must respond with a cors allow origin header that specifies the url your app runs at.. If you don't own the server `...` you're kinda screwed, unless you can get away with the reduced functionality of a no-cors request. Your options in those cases usually come down to writing a proxy service you host, your app contacts your proxy, your proxy fetches the resource at `...` without cors

Comment: ... these three dots are the localhost where my project is run.

Comment: No probs.. Just remember that if the response to the browser issuing an OPTIONS is a failure (error 404, error 500 etc) you'll also get a CORS fail... All the info you need to resolve this is right there in the network tab of your browserdev console; 1) why is it issuing an OPTIONS if it's same origin, 2) what does the OPTIONS contain,  3) what is the response to the options, 4) what is the CORS failure message in the console -> if the request succeeds but lacks the necessaries, configure the server. If th request fails, fix the request